# How to deploy Webpack build to AWS from Bitbucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, continuous-integration, bitbucket, continuous-deployment

I have a React application that I am bundling using Webpack. The app relies on a MongoDB database and a Node/Express server to field the backend of the app (API requests, etc.).
I want to set up continuous integration/deployment (C.I/D.), but am not sure where to start. As my app's GIT repo is with Bitbucket and I have had experience with AWS in the past, it would be good to enable C.I/D. using these. How do I go about this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Jenkins to build your project from BitBucket.

Make use of AWS CodePipeline and AWS CodeDeploy for continuous delivery on AWS.

Jenkins gives you the flexibility to work with any source control system, and has plugins for AWS CodePipeline.

From AWS CodePipeline, you can configure a stage to call a Jenkins build job.

I've been using this system in production for quite some time now, without any issues.

Comment: Where in the deployment process do you run the webpack 'build' command - do you add a BeforeInstall hook to the AppSpec file that AWS Code Deploy uses?